# get exact coordinates of animating element with d3.js

Tags: d3.js

In this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qizovu/edit?html,js,output), I am trying to position the horizontal line to the smaller circle in the animating group but the jsbin is using getBoundingClientRect and some arbitrary values to get there.

I wanted to use this value:

```
d3.select('.circle-guide').attr('cx')
```

But it always returns the same value and does not take the transform into account.

How can I get the coordinates of a n animating element?

Comment: The circle guide is moving with the help of transform rotate. There is no cx on the circle-guide.

Comment: I was having trouble with this when I solved your previous problem. I did try using .attr('cx') with no luck. Looks like Cyril explained why :))

Comment: @thatOneGuy yeah, I need to work it out from t and the degrees.  Interesting problem, thanks anyway